# Decorators with babel, unexpected token

Tags: javascript, babeljs, decorator, browserify, ecmascript-next

I'm trying to use decorators on classes in React, using babelify. I have the 'es7.decorators' option applied in babel, but I keep getting an 'unexpected token' error when it encounters the '@' character.

Anyone have any ideas? A simple example is below.

Decorator:

```
export default function(Component) {
  return class extends Component {
    constructor() {...}
  }
}
```

Class:

```
import myDecorator from 'decorator';

@myDecorator
class MyClass{...}
```

I'm using [babelify](https://github.com/babel/babelify#babelify) (Browserify transform for Babel):

```
browserify().transform(babelify.configure({
  optional: ['es7.decorators']
})
```

Comment: How exactly did you enable optional `es7.decorators` transformer? Please, provide your `.babelrc` file and command you're using to run or compile your ES7 source code.

Comment: `browserify(...).transform(babelify.configure({ optional: ['es7.decorators'] })`

I know this works, as I get a decorator specific error if I add a semi-colon after the decorator.

Comment: Well, your code works fine for me, so something is wrong with the way you're running/compiling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @LeonidBeschastny for mentioning `.babelrc` file, using the config file decorators work correctly, using the setup described on the babelify readme doesn't work, for whatever reason (not sure if my setup or something else).

Comment: I think you should accept your answer. At least, until someone will give you a better reasoning why `babelify.configure` didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else ran into this problem, I was having the same problem.

I think there were breaking changes outlined here: http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/03/31/5.0.0/#babelrc

All I needed to do was add { "stage": 1 } to my babelrc, which tells babel to compile with the experimental features, one of which is the es7 decorator.

Comment: This was correct for babel as of v6, my original question was for v5. Now though, it appears you need to use `babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy` to get them to work, as it looks like decorator support was pulled out of the stage presets (could be wrong, but I had to add the plugin to get them to work properly). Might help someone!

Comment: and now we are on to bable 7 and I'm having this issue again